# Special character gets encoded. Dont know how to revert it?

Tags: php, wordpress, decode

Im using the function get_query_var() to retrive my url path.

My url path looks like: `/categories/500-Beställning`

Now to retrieve this I use:

`$url = get_query_var('title2');`

If I `var_dump($url);` I get: `string(29) "500-Best%C3%A4llning"`.

Now the letter `ä` is encoded. I have tried the function `utf8_decode`, which did not work, to decode it. But I am not quite sure to what is is encoded and how to correctly decode it. Thanks!

Comment: `utf8_decode` "Converts a string with ISO-8859-1 characters encoded with UTF-8 to single-byte ISO-8859-1". You aren't dealing with character encoding issues here.

Comment: @Quentin Yea, I figuerd it was that. `urldecode()` worked perfectly. Will accept your answer as soon as i can!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To decode URL encoded data, use [urldecode](http://php.net/urldecode):

```
<?php
  $string = "500-Best%C3%A4llning";
  print urldecode($string);
?>
```